# Tag 'logcat' and 'android-logcat' are synonyms, but not marked as such

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

The tags [logcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logcat) and [android-logcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-logcat) should be marked as synonyms. They even have the exact same description, but are not marked as synonyms.

I suggest 'logcat' being a synonym of 'android-logcat' as 'android-logcat' is more descriptive.

Comment: I think logcat only needed here. android or java, logcat is one.

Comment: [Logcat](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html) is specific to Android and not java.

Comment: I'd go so far as to say that [tag:android-logcat] should be burninated, since as you say, it is specific to Android, so why include android in the tag name?

Comment: Out of the corner of my eye, I read this as 'lolcat'. Thinking to myself, 'we don't really need that tag, do we?'

Comment: @RivieraKid I think we should not, as I had the same problem that mikeTheLiar had ^ (or at least what he said he had, you can't never be sure)